# How set in mysql query a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

What i have:

```
$table_name_arcticles = 'arcticles';
$arcticles_count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categories_id` ="  . $data['id']);
```

What i need, something like this:

```
$table_name_arcticles = 'arcticles';
$arcticles_count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM $table_name_arcticles WHERE `categories_id` ="  . $data['id']);
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: This should work...?

Comment: btw, the word is "articles" and not "arcticles". I doubt that's a word in any language. So again: *"what's the problem?"* - You didn't say, so I for one cannot guess and as to where you're pre-querying from with `$data['id']`.

Comment: I'm on the fence to follow the "unclear" vote to close so far, as there stands to be a duplicate for this. If you're not going to tell us what's "not working", then wait longer and don't make "us" wait neither. You're not only wasting other people's time, but yours also. So use `mysqli_error($connection)` on the query then come back and tell us what that error was. If you left the question, then that doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- arcticles is what I call ice cubes in a language I just made up.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Funny you should say that, I had that very same thought *lol!* GMTA ;-)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: i found Answer: $arcticles_count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'total_count' FROM ` $table_name_articles` WHERE ` categories_id` ="  . $data['id']);

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
$table_name_arcticles = 'arcticles';
$query="SELECT * FROM ".$table_name_arcticles." WHERE `categories_id` ="  . $data['id'];
$arcticles_count = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: how you know that it is not working. when you know then please give answer.

Comment: please show below code after $articale_count variable then i will fix that. problem is coming after that.

Comment: You are getting error in mysqli_fetch_assoc(), not from above code, update the code